# If in_array then include - newbie

Tags: arrays, include

i'm starting with php now, and i'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
   <!-- begin homepage ads -->
    <?php
        $homepage = array("/", "/?subtopic=latestnews");
        $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if(in_array($homepage==$currentpage)) {
        include('pages/newsticker.php');
        }
    ?>
    <!-- end homepage ads -->
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? being messing witht his code for some time and couldn't solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in_array needs 2 parameters, needle and haystack.  Change your if statement to the following:

```
if(in_array($currentpage, $homepage))
```

For in_array reference, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1):

You should write this line

```
if(in_array($homepage==$currentpage)) {
```

like this:

```
if(in_array($currentpage, $homepage))
```

Check the manual http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php

Comment: Thanks for your help, Dusty was 2 minutes quicker, both answers worked!